# Android - ListView items hidden by soft input

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, window-soft-input-mode

I have a `ListView` with a RelativeLayout containing an `EditText` below it.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10sp"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:stackFromBottom="false"
    android:transcriptMode="normal">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chatInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        style="@style/NomadlyTheme.EditText"
        android:hint="Enter text here"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I click on the `EditText` and the soft input show up, I want the `ListView` to show the same items that were displayed before the keyboard appeared, from the bottom at least:

Before soft input:

```
 __________ 
|    7     |
|    8     |
|    9     |  <- ListView
|    10    |
|____11____|
|__________|  <- EditText
```

After soft input:

```
 __________
|    9     |
|    10    |
|____11____|
|__________|
| Keyboard |
|__________|
```

Now, when the last element of the `ListView` is visible, the above happens. But when only middle elements are visible, this happens:

Before soft input:

```
 __________ 
|    3     |
|    4     |
|    5     |  <- ListView
|    6     |
|____7_____|
|__________|  <- EditText
```

After soft input:

```
 __________
|    3     |
|    4     |
|____5_____|
|__________|
| Keyboard |
|__________|
```

I have set `windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize` for this activity in my manifest. Please advice me on how I can get the items to scroll up.

Comment: Remember the height of the list before the keyboard pops up, subtract the height afterwards, then do `list.scroll(-deltaHeight)`

Comment: I considered that, but you can't get soft input events, right? So assuming I store the height somehwere, when exactly do I recalculate it?

Comment: you could try `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"` on your activtiy in manifest and listen for the change

Comment: But the callback to `onConfigurationChange` need not happen BEFORE the keyboard shows up, right?